# Can a set view of a webpage turned into something like a desktop widget?

Tags: webpage, viewer, desktop-gadget

**edit** I'm interested to do this on Windows, Linux and Mac. :)

I am curious if there is already a way to create something like a desktop widget out of only a selected part of a webpage.

There are many relatively stable URLs and page structures on the web, like [a random section in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random).

My vision is to have a little widget that displays a selected, specific part of a webpage, and say updates the view once daily.

I've once read that there were research into allowing only 'clips' (selected parts?) of OS windows to be shown next to each other, live, I'd like something similar with web pages.

Is there already a way that I could just point to some part of a webpage and pin it on my virtual desktop like a poster?

Comment: You may want to specify your OS, I believe OSX's dashboard has an option for this type of thing, and I would bet that Rainmeter on Windows does as well.

Comment: @nerdwaller is right, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Clip) (search for 'web clip' in the text).

Comment: I edited my question, I'm interested in the three major desktop OS categories. (One per answer would be fine.)

Answer (score 0):

For the Mac, you might be interested in Conjure, http://conjurebunny.com/Conjure/Welcome.html.  While I don't see a way to capture a web page on to a Conjure desktop per se, e.g., get a screenshot to it, it does create a desktop on which you can drag and drop images/graphics, as well as write on (just start typing on the desktop, and a box will enclose your text).  Images can be freely re-szied, and you can create containers on the desktop with Conjure objects inside them. Everything can be freely arranged, etc.

I have found Conjure to be useful tool to create a pseudo desktop for complex environments where you might want to see some screenshots, contents of subdirectories, and read some text notes (on the desktop) before launching a program.  You can create aliases/links to programs (to launch them from the conjure desktop), etc.  So I have different conjure desktops for different versions of a program/environment (often with a screenshot showing what the program/GUI should look like once it is opened). I suspect what you would want is something like a "clip to conjure desktop" feature; maybe there is a way to do it.